# What's the point of equipping a ring without an ability?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I've come across multiple rings with seemingly no use. They have no abilities, no stat buffs, and they don't visually appear on my character when equipped. Is there any purpose to these rings outside of selling them?

[image: Bronze ring with no abilities]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no point**, and they have no other purpose.

Like gems and other Common jewellery these rings are just conveniently light-weight valuables, good for selling.

Comment: What about cosmetic purposes? Can jewelery be seen during gameplay and cutscenes?

Comment: @MeanGreen They cannot be seen, no. The OP already pointed that out :)